# DevExpress Chart Control showing/plotting integer values as decimals that doesn't make sense mathematically

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

So the question is why is it displaying data in decimals that do not make sense, here's a screenshot[image]

Here's the console output:

```
fVal: 1| fTime: 06:00:00
fVal: 1| fTime: 08:00:00
fVal: 1| fTime: 09:00:00
fVal: 1| fTime: 10:00:00
fVal: 1| fTime: 12:00:00
fVal: 2| fTime: 13:00:00
fVal: 2| fTime: 18:00:00
```

As you can see the values are not decimals. But when plotted on the chart it shows as a decimal.
Things I have tried:

1. Using devexpress' best practice example
2. using both .add, .addrange, and .addpoint methods but they all
   display the same bug.
3. Inserting a fresh chart control.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub initSeriesData_Hourly() 'Count how many documents in a day is processed(globally)
        Dim dataList As List(Of TimeSpan) = datasetHourly()
        Dim dtList As New List(Of DateTime)
        If Not dataList Is Nothing Then
            For x As Integer = 0 To dataList.Count - 1
                Dim dt As DateTime = New DateTime() + dataList.Item(x)
                dtList.Add(dt)
            Next
        End If

        Dim dataList_Count = countDateTime(dtList)
        chart_ProcessedDocuments.RefreshData()
        Dim pDoc_Series_1 As Series = chart_ProcessedDocuments.Series("Processed Documents(Hourly)")


        If Not dataList_Count Is Nothing Then

            Dim val As New List(Of Integer)
            Dim time_ As New List(Of TimeSpan)
            For hourData As Integer = 0 To dataList_Count.Count - 1
                Dim timeSpanSplit = dataList_Count.Item(hourData).Split("|")
                time_.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timeSpanSplit(0)))
                val.Add(timeSpanSplit(1))
                Console.WriteLine(timeSpanSplit(0) + "|" + timeSpanSplit(1))
            Next


            'Dim pointscount = 24

            'Dim pointsList As New List(Of SeriesPoint)
            Dim fTime_List As New List(Of TimeSpan)
            Dim fVal_List As New List(Of Integer)

            For i As Integer = 0 To 23
                Dim intTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(i) 'Converts integer to timespan format
                Dim fVal As Integer
                Dim fTime As TimeSpan
                If time_.Count > 0 Then
                    For j As Integer = 0 To time_.Count - 1
                        If intTime = time_(j) Then
                            fVal = val(j)
                            fTime = intTime
                            Console.WriteLine("fVal: " + fVal.ToString + "| fTime: " + fTime.ToString)
                        Else
                            fVal = 0
                            fTime = intTime
                        End If
                        fTime_List.Add(fTime)
                        fVal_List.Add(fVal)
                    Next
                End If
            Next

            If fVal_List.Count > 0 Then
                For length = 0 To fVal_List.Count - 1
                    Dim pointPlot As New SeriesPoint(fTime_List.Item(length), fVal_List.Item(length))
                    pDoc_Series_1.Points.Add(pointPlot)
                Next
            End If
        Else

        End If
    End Sub
```

Sorry the code doesn't look good as I have been trying to solve the issue for 2 days now.

Comment: Have you chcked values in fVal_List in watch window? Not via console output. The values in the chart seem to be divided by 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the loop is going over 24 and every iteration past that somehow reduces/divides the plotted value.

Changed the loop to this:

```
For index_0 As Integer = 0 To cTime_List.Count - 1
            For index_1 As Integer = 0 To time_.Count - 1
                If cTime_List.Item(index_0) = time_.Item(index_1) Then
                    Dim oldVal = cVal_List.Item(index_0)

                    cVal_List.Item(index_0) = val.Item(index_1)

                    Console.WriteLine(cTime_List.Item(index_0).ToString + "=" + time_.Item(index_1).ToString)
                    Console.WriteLine(oldVal.ToString + "<->" + val.Item(index_1).ToString)
                End If
            Next
            'Console.WriteLine(index_0)
            Dim pointPlot_1 As New SeriesPoint(cTime_List.Item(index_0), (cVal_List.Item(index_0)))
            pDoc_Series_1.Points.Add(pointPlot_1)
Next
```